# Redirect_uri_mismatch in Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.1 on Ubuntu and Nginx as a reverse proxy to connect to my app in my  local server. It works simply like this:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass         http://localhost:5002;   
}
```

The problem starts when trying to external login with Google. My app is OK on windows/IIS but when use proxy_pass and Nginx,

> The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:5002/signin-google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client

I need to change the outgoing url from `http://localhost:5002/signin-google` to `http://example.com/signin-google` in NginX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications use HTTP `Host` header to determine what is the hostname they are running on. By default, nginx does not relay the `Host` header to upstream.

You need to add `proxy_set_header Host $host` to your configuration, this tells nginx to send `Host` header to proxied server.

Without the `Host` header, the application will use hostname and port as the value.

Comment: IDK why your answer was even downvoted. This actually worked perfectly well. Thank you!